# Why isn't a painting drawn to the screen?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have this simple code which is supposed to have three panels and draws and oval at the top left corner of each panel

```
public class main1 extends JPanel {
    public main1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        JPanel1 panel1 = new JPanel1(Color.YELLOW);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel1 panel2 = new JPanel1(Color.red);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        JPanel1 panel3 = new JPanel1(Color.pink);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.add(panel1);
        this.add(panel2);
        this.add(panel3);
    }

    class JPanel1 extends JPanel{
        Color c;
        public JPanel1(Color c) {
            this.c = c;


        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println(this.getBounds().x);
            g.setColor(c);
            g.drawOval(this.getBounds().x, this.getBounds().y, 200, 200);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Two Panels");
        f.setContentPane(new main1());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

however, it only seems to draw the first oval of the first panel and ignores the rest.
can somebody explain. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [getBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds%28%29) as it gives the component location relative to its parent. Use panel's coordinates and its width and height instead. In your example you are painting outside the boundaries of the panels. For example use this to draw an oval:

```
g.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Some side notes:

- Do not call `setSize()`, override panel's `getPreferredSize()` and `pack()` the frame. For example:

  ```
  public Dimension getPreferredSize(){return new Dimension(400, 400);}
  ```

  Then, add `frame.pack();` before making the frame visible.
- See Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).
- See [Performing Custom Painting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by relative to it's parent location?

Comment: @user3929076 it is the location of the panel within the frame. For example, for the third panel, its bounds `x = 188`, but its `width = 94`. So you're painting outside the bounds of the panel. Also, note that coordinate (0,0) represents the upper left corner of the panel.